# Object not found on codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have codeigniter installed on my localhost

The main.php controller is

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this -> login();
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    public function login_validation() {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|md5');

        if($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            redirect('main/members');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }

    }

}
```

The login is working page is coming,but after I fill the username and password,should take me to login/main/login_validation  and from there the function login_validation() should either redirect to main/members or show me the login page.But what happens is when I submit the form,the object not found error is coming.Can anyone help me out?

form is

form_open('main/login_validation');

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Is the main/members supposed to be a password protected area? If so, I don't see how you are checking anything with the code you have supplied.

Comment: You should also post the entire form code from the view, so we can see exactly what you're trying to work with.

Comment: does the function `members()` exist in the `main` controller? it looks like you should be passing validation and being redirected

Comment: a couple side notes. I see you are using MD5 to prep your password. MD5 is outdated and should no longer be used if security is of any importance to you. If you are using PHP 5.5 please look at [password_hash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) or if using 5.3 - 5.4 look at the [compatibility library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). very good, and very easy to use. secondly, look at your code duplication loading the 'login' view. `redirect()` back to `main/login` instead. this will also prevent the 'do you want to submit again?' error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer what I think your question is getting at, you're using the form_validation class wrong. You should be testing whether or not the form_validation->run() is TRUE (all fields passed validation) or FALSE (there was an error in one or more of the inputs). Structure you code like such:

```
public function login_validation() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|md5');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('main/members');
    }
}
```

This is covered in the CodeIgniter documentation [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#thecontroller).

Comment: his first `IF` is checking for `TRUE`. `if($this->form_validation->run())` is a perfectly legit way to check for a boolean. if you are going to spell out `TRUE` OR `FALSE`, you should also be using `===`

Comment: Fair enough, I just prefer to go the way the documentation states. And thanks for the comment on comparison operators, I changed it to check for type as well.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller ..you could try this..

```
function index()
{
 //This method will have the credentials validation
 $this->load->library('form_validation');

 $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

 if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
 {
 //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page

 $this->load->view('login');

 }
else
{

 $this->check_database();
     //redirect('home');
 }

}
 function check_database()
{
//Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
$username = $this->input->post('username');
$password = $this->input->post('password');

//query the database
$query_result = $this->model_login->login($username, $password);

if($query_result)
{


    $this->load->view('main/members');

}
else
{


    redirect('login');

}
}
```

in model

```
 function login($username,$password){

 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `username`= '".$username."' AND
          password='".$password."' LIMIT 1");


     if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;



}
```